# R shiny Filter issues

Tags: r, filter, shiny

Having trouble with executing functioning filters in my R shiny project (not sure if it is an issue with the UI or the server) --> neighbourhood and number of reviews will not communicate with room type and region filters.

**Server Code**

```
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

# Define server that analyzes the Singapore Airbnb Listings
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Create an output variable for problem description
  output$text <- renderText({

    "This project uses the dataset .................FILL OUT LATER........."

  })


  # Create a descriptive table for NBHD
  output$table1 <- renderPrint({

    # Connect to the sidebar of file input
    inFile <- input$file

    if(is.null(inFile))
      return("Please Upload A File For Analysis")

    # Read input file
    mydata <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    attach(mydata)

    # Filter the data for different Room Types and Regions
    target1 <- c(input$room_type)
    neighbourhood_df <- filter(mydata, room_type %in% target1)

    # Create a table for NBHD
    table(mydata$neighbourhood)

  })

  # Create a descriptive table for # of reviews
  output$table2 <- renderPrint({

    # Connect to the sidebar of file input
    inFile1 <- input$file

    if(is.null(inFile1))
      return("Please Upload A File For Analysis")

    # Read input file
    mydata1 <- read.csv(inFile1$datapath)
    attach(mydata1)

    # Filter the data for different Room Type and Region
    target3 <- c(input$room_type)
    target4 <- c(input$region)
    number_of_reviews_df <- filter(mydata1, room_type %in% target3 & region %in% target4)

    # Create a table for Rooms
    table(mydata1$number_of_reviews)

  })


  # Create a map output variable
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    # Connect to the sidebar of file input
    inFile2 <- input$file

    if(is.null(inFile2))
      return(NULL)

    # Read input file
    mydata2 <- read.csv(inFile2$datapath)
    attach(mydata2)

    # Filter the data for different Room Type and Region
    target5 <- c(input$room_type)
    target6 <- c(input$region)
    map_df <- filter(mydata2, room_type %in% target5 & region %in% target6)

    # Create colors with a categorical color function
    color <- colorFactor(rainbow(9), mydata2$neighbourhood)

    # Create the leaflet function for data
    leaflet(map_df) %>%

      # Set the default view
      setView(lng = 103.8608, lat = 1.2834, zoom = 12) %>%

      # Provide tiles
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%

      # Add circles
      addCircleMarkers(
        radius = 2,
        lng= mydata2$longitude,
        lat= mydata2$latitude,
        stroke= FALSE,
        fillOpacity=0.1,
        color=color(neighbourhood)
      ) %>%

      # Add legends for different nbhds
      addLegend(
        "bottomleft",
        pal=color,
        values=neighbourhood,
        opacity=0.5,
        title="Singapore Neighbourhood"
      )
  })
})
```

**UI Code**

```
    library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinythemes)

# Define UI for application that analyzes the patterns of crimes in DC
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Change the theme to flatly
  theme = shinytheme("flatly"),

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Patterns of Crimes in Washington DC"),

  # Three sidebars for uploading files, selecting Room types and Regions
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      # Create a file input
      fileInput("file","Choose A CSV File Please",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),

      # Create a multiple checkbox input for Room Type
      checkboxGroupInput("RoomType",
                         "Room Type:",
                         c("Private Room","Entire home/apt","Shared room")
      ),

      hr(),
      helpText("Please Select The Room type for listing analysis"),
      helpText("You Can Choose More Than One"),

      hr(),
      hr(),

      # Create a multiple checkbox input for Regions
      checkboxGroupInput("Region",
                         "Region:",
                         choices = list("Central Region"= 1,"East Region"= 2,"North Region"= 3,"North-East Region"= 4,
                                        "West Region"= 5)
      ),

      hr(),
      helpText("Please Select The Regions You Would Like To Analyze For Listing Patterns"),
      helpText("You Can Choose More Than One")
    ),

    # Make the sidebar on the right of the webpage
    position = "right",
    fluid = TRUE,



    # Create two tabs
    mainPanel(
      hr(),
      tabsetPanel(type="tabs",

                  #Add a tab for Analysis Overview
                  tabPanel("Analysis Overview", textOutput("text")),

                  #Add a tab for Room type and Region
                  tabPanel("Listing Analysis",

                           #Add two subtabs
                           tabsetPanel(
                             tabPanel("Neighbourhood",verbatimTextOutput("table1")),
                             tabPanel("Number of Reviews",verbatimTextOutput("table2"))
                           )
                  ),


                  #Tab for the Leaflet Map
                  tabPanel("Map", leafletOutput("map", height=630))
      )
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: FYI, your formatting is very hard to read. Your code is partly blocked but partly not. Please check the preview when posting. Also, feel free to use the edit button to make fixes. And welcome to the site.

Comment: thanks adam will make those changes now

Answer (score 0):

In your UI you call the variables `RoomType` and `Region`, but in your server code you call them `input$room_type` and `input$region`. The `input$` is correct, but the variable names are different. So you are basically doing a filter on `room_type %in% NULL`.

**Edit for Clarification:**

In the UI you have:

```
# Create a multiple checkbox input for Room Type
checkboxGroupInput("RoomType",
                   "Room Type:",
                   c("Private Room","Entire home/apt","Shared room")
)
```

In the Server you have:

```
# Filter the data for different Room Type and Region
target3 <- c(input$room_type)
```

`room_type` is not a valid input from the UI. It may be a field in your dataframe, but not in your UI. So you need:

```
# Filter the data for different Room Type and Region
target3 <- c(input$RoomType)
```

Comment: i did not attach the csv file with this but it is a singapore airbnb data set and the variables for those two are 'room_type' and 'region'. I believe the UI variable names are arbitrary.

Comment: `input` points to input objects in the UI. So `input$RoomType` is the value that is selected in the checkboxGroupInput.

Comment: Hi Adam I made those edits and it still appears to not be filtering- not sure why